# How to call my function in a LINQ to Entities queries

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

### Problem

I use linq to return a list of anonymous objects

```
from s in _subsidiaryService.Repository.Query()
   where  s.Title.ToLower().Contains(term) ||
   s.Description.ToLower().Contains(term) ||
   s.District.ToLower().Contains(term)
   select new
              {
                  label = s.Title
                  ,
                  desc = s.Description
                  ,
                  value = s.ID
                  ,
                  icon = Url.Content(Path.Combine(string.Format(Constants.RelativePathSubsidiary, s.ID), SmallIconFileName))  //Problem line!!
              }
```

The line `icon` is where the problem is

Linq to Entities does not recognize `Path.Combine` or `string.Format`

### Questions

I have two questions:

1. How can I run and Path.Combine string.format inside my queries
2. How do I create functions that run inside my queries?  e.g:

**Code sample**

```
from s in _subsidiaryService.Repository.Query()
   where  s.Title.ToLower().Contains(term) ||
   s.Description.ToLower().Contains(term) ||
   s.District.ToLower().Contains(term)
   select new
              {
                  label = s.Title
                  ,
                  desc = s.Description
                  ,
                  value = s.ID
                  ,
                  icon = getIconPath(s.SmallIconFileName)
              }
```

**My method**

```
public string getIconPath(Guid id, sring fileName) {
    return Url.Content(Path.Combine(string.Format(Constants.RelativePathSubsidiary, id), fileName));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to:

```
(from s in _subsidiaryService.Repository.Query()
where  s.Title.ToLower().Contains(term) ||
s.Description.ToLower().Contains(term) ||
s.District.ToLower().Contains(term)
select s).AsEnumerable().Select(s => new { label = s.Title, desc = s.Description, value = s.ID, icon = getIconPath(s.SmallIconFileName) });
```

The `.AsEnumerable()` switches it from the query to in memory operations, so it doesn't try to map the functions to the database.

Its worth noting though that this means it runs everything up to the `.AsEnumerable` on the database, pulls it locally to an `IEnumerable` then starts iterating it to do the anonymous object creation.  So there are performance implications to doing this.  It may be worthwhile to trim the columns you are selecting by using an anonymous object or making sure all of your `Where` filtering is done prior to the `AsEnumerable`.